# How much does a LEGO character weigh?

Tags: minifigures, size

I am doing a science project and I need a 50g passenger for a car.  I need to know how much a LEGO character weighs!

Comment: does it need to be the size of a minifig? or could you use a [TECHNIC figure](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/TECHNIC_Figure) instead? I think they're about 50g to 60g...

Comment: @HorusKol: You're way off, according to bricklink it's around 12.4g.

Comment: @Henrik - I saw something else on bricklink that said 0.15 lbs - which is about 60g... but not 100% they're talking about the figure, or the figure plus a couple of other bits...

Comment: Just a tip: if you are doing a science project, then you should personally and demonstrably make sure your passenger is exactly 50g. References like "some users at a public forum said so" are considered to be highly unscientific. Get a scale and do some measurements :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### About 3g (2.98g)

[image]

Based on a small sample of Minifigure part data provided by [Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/main.page), a minifigure in it's most basic form (Head, Torso Assembly and Legs Assembley) weighs about 3g.

A [small hairpiece](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3901&idColor=11#T=C&C=11) or [cap](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4485#T=C) will add about 0.3g - 0.4g

Large hairpieces/headgear can add about [0.9g](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=92083#T=C) - [1.0g](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=x161#T=C).